# Visual Studio 2012 UI customization

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-addins

Are there any add-ins available that let you customize the UI look and feel for Visual Studio 2012 IDE?

Comment: "Shopping" questions are generally off-topic here on [so].

Comment: But its still very much related to productivity. For the first time I felt something higher wasn't good enough as lower is with VS 2012

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This extension gives you basic control over the VS2012 colour palette:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05

Unfortunately there's no control over icons, appearance/roundness of windows etc in this extension however.

Answer (score 5):

[Visual Studio 2012 Color Theme Editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05) is for you, as [Daniel said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12347936/588868).

There is also an open  source project that can restore VS 2010 icons in VS 2012 :

[Visual Studio Icon Patcher](http://vsip.codeplex.com/).

I wouldn't use it anyways, as it's more a hack, than a real solution.

Comment: Thanks for the mentioning about Icon Patcher. I would play around with it, (just) for the heck of it.